# Ignore First Mention but Flag Duplicates in Column R

Tags: r, duplicates

A column contains duplicates, the first mention of a value is not problematic and do not want to flag as '1' for problematic... However, duplicates of a value are problematic and want to label with '1'.

How to do this?

Example:

```
1234   0
1234   1
1234   1
```

Comment: Try `+(duplicated(df$col))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(val = c(1234, 1234, 1234))
df$tag <- as.integer(duplicated(df$val))
df
#    val tag
# 1 1234   0
# 2 1234   1
# 3 1234   1
```